# Warning: Division by zero in C:\xampp\htdocs\engine\core.php on line 629

Tags: php

I'm new to PHP and I have an error on my website and can't figure out the right way to fix it.

The error:

```
Warning: Division by zero
```

The code I'm using:

```
public function percent($num_amount, $num_total)
{
    $count1 = $num_amount / $num_total;
    $count2 = $count1 * 100;
    $count = round($count2);

    return $count;
}
```

I know it has something to do with dividing by 0 which obviously can't.
But how do I change that and fix this error?

Comment: Only divide by `$num_total` if the value of said variable is higher than 0.

Comment: "I know it has something to do with dividing by 0 which obviously can't.". It obviously does.

Comment: Divisions by 0 are mathematically impossible. Then, test $num_total and divide only if ($num_total != 0).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply....

```
public function percent($num_amount, $num_total)
{
    if($num_total > 0){
       $count1 = $num_amount / $num_total;
       $count2 = $count1 * 100;
       $count = round($count2);
       return $count;
    }else{
       return 0; // or whatever you want
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If `$num_total` is zero, then check if `$num_amount` is also zero. If it is, then return a value that's appropriate (possibly 100%). If `$num_amount` is not also zero then you have some logic error which you should flag.

Comment: Excuse me, but 0/0 is NOT determined. You can't say an unique number **x** to answer **0/0=x**.

Comment: Indeed you are correct. Hence why I say *appropriate*. Perhaps you should error in that case too.

Comment: Yes, this would be the best option. Because somewhere there is a flaw in logic allowing $num_total to be 0 at this point. Better to raise an error and treat it, or prevent the error.